# A* algorithm infinite while-loop

Tags: java, algorithm, while-loop, path-finding, a-star

I've been attempting to follow some pseudocode, namely

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/  &

http://mat.uab.cat/~alseda/MasterOpt/AStar-Algorithm.pdf ,

to create an A star pathfinding algorithm for a four-directional tile/cell-based map with obstacles. I understand the concept, and I could definitely explain how it should work in words/images, but putting it into code is proving challenging. For a few days now whenever I've run my program it crashes and I have to manually stop the application. I believe this is due to an infinite while-loop. This confuses me because the program should exit the while-loop once its found the end destination, but obviously that isn't working. This is the code which I think should make it exit the while-loop once the destination is found:

```
if (n.getX() == end.getX() && n.getY() == end.getY()) {
            currentNode = n;
            break;
        }
```

I hope this isn't too much code to put in this post, but this is the meat of my algorithm with comments on what I think each piece is doing:

```
public void attempt2() {
        double leastF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        // Initializes the starting Node and, in the beginning, currentNode is the same
        // as the starting node
        Node start = new Node(r.getCell());
        Node currentNode = start;
        start.setParent(start);
        closed.add(start);
        open.add(start);
        start.setEnd(destinationCP);
        start.calculateH();
        start.isCalculatedH();

        while (open.size() > 0) {

            // Finds the node with the least F score on Open
            for (Node n : open) {
                // Calculates the H-score if it hasn't been already
                if (n.haveNotCalculatedH()) {
                    n.setEnd(destinationCP);
                    n.calculateH();
                    n.isCalculatedH();
                }
                // Calculates the g-score, with 1 being the value/distance of a cell
                n.setAdditiveDistanceG(n.getAdditiveDistanceG() + 1);
                // Calculates the F-score
                n.calculateF();

                // Actually finds the least F score in the open list and sets currentNode to the
                // node with the least F
                if (n.getTotalCostF() < leastF) {
                    leastF = n.getTotalCostF();
                    currentNode = n;
                }
            }
            //

            // Creates easy-access variables for the x and y values of the node on open with
            // the least F score
            int thisX = currentNode.getX();
            int thisY = currentNode.getY();

            // if this cell (cell in open w least F) is the end destination cell, stop the calculations
            if (thisX == end.getX() && thisY == end.getY()) {
                break;
            }
            //

            // Generate 1-4 successors if Robot can pass into the cell
            if (World.getCell(thisX + 1, thisY).canEnter(r)) {
                successors.add(new Node(World.getCell(thisX + 1, thisY)));
            }
            if (World.getCell(thisX, thisY + 1).canEnter(r)) {
                successors.add(new Node(World.getCell(thisX, thisY + 1)));
            }
            if (World.getCell(thisX - 1, thisY).canEnter(r)) {
                successors.add(new Node(World.getCell(thisX - 1, thisY)));
            }
            if (World.getCell(thisX, thisY - 1).canEnter(r)) {
                successors.add(new Node(World.getCell(thisX, thisY - 1)));
            }
            //

            /*
             * Loops through each of the 1-4 neighbors to currentNode (I need to add in to
             * erase & add to open/closed every one in here so its empty before new ones are
             * generated
             */
            for (Node n : successors) {
                double successorCurrentCost = 0;

                // if this successor is already in the closed list, skip doing all the code for
                // this node and add this successor's parent (currentNode) to the closed list
                if (isInClosed(n)) {
                    continue;
                }

                // if this is the goal/end node, exit the 'successors' for-loop. the step that
                // follows this (exiting the loop) is that this particular node/successor is
                // added to the closed list
                if (n.getX() == end.getX() && n.getY() == end.getY()) {
                    currentNode = n;
                    break;
                }
                //

                // Calculates the F cost for each successor to currentNode
                if (n.haveNotCalculatedH()) {
                    n.setEnd(destinationCP);
                    n.calculateH();
                    n.isCalculatedH();
                }
                n.setAdditiveDistanceG(n.getAdditiveDistanceG() + currentNode.getAdditiveDistanceG());
                n.calculateF();
                successorCurrentCost = n.getTotalCostF();
                //


                if (!isInOpen(n) && n.getAdditiveDistanceG() > successorCurrentCost
                        || n.getAdditiveDistanceG() > successorCurrentCost && !isInClosed(n)) {
                    open.add(n);
                    if (n.haveNotCalculatedH()) {
                        n.setEnd(destinationCP);
                        n.calculateH();
                        n.isCalculatedH();
                    }
                } else if (isInClosed(n) && n.getAdditiveDistanceG() <= successorCurrentCost) {
                    successorCurrentCost = n.getAdditiveDistanceG();
                    n.setParent(currentNode);
                } else {
                    successorCurrentCost = n.getAdditiveDistanceG();
                    n.setParent(currentNode);
                }
                if (isInClosed(n)) {
                    closed.remove(n);
                    open.add(n);
                }
            }
            closed.add(currentNode);
            if (thisX == end.getX() && thisY == end.getY()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (currentNode.getMyCell() != this.destinationCP) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: open list is empty");
            return;
        } else {
            createPath();
        }
    }
```

I am aware that there are a few things that should be changed in this code, however I am most concerned about the while loop never being terminated. Any other comments about my code are appreciated but definitely not necessary.

Comment: Check out https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to help you debug your code.

Comment: The `break` statement you are referring to breaks out of the surrounding `for` loop (not the outer `while` loop). Code-Apprentice is right: Time to debug!